# What is this new "optimization tab" for adsense?

Tags: google-adsense

I checked adsense today for my website and as it was loading, I noticed a #1 on a red circle next to a new "optimization" tab. I then click into it and nothing appeared on the screen. I figured maybe its my opera browser again. So I pull up firefox (a browser that works with google) and tried the "optimization" tab there. I get the same thing. Nothing. I tried clicking the side menu items, and still get nothing.

So my question then is, what is this optimization tab and will the tab really help me monetize better on my site? or is it just another bug google developed for publishers?

Comment: I do not see this tab. It may be that Google thinks that you can do something to increase revenue. I also feel that it is really good that you actually get a clear report! ;-) With all the work you have done? You should. Cheers!!

Comment: This all feels familiar. I might have gotten the tab before... I just cannot remember. It may be why I added the text based ads mid-page.